# Magento 2 - Save value from custom input field to quote_item

Tags: magento2, quoteitem

I have created an extra field Delivery in **quote_item**, I have also created a **input field** that customers can type in the delivery date they wished, on product page.

How can I save the value from this input field to the table **quote_item** when customer click on the **add to basket** button?

I can in this file `\vendor\magento\module-checkout\Controller\Cart` see that values to be added to the quote_item is taken from,

```
$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
```

So maybe I could just ask how I can pass my custom value from input field to the `$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();` ?

Comment: My suggestion is to add an additional option instead of creating new field and store in the database.

Comment: I have the same logic with another data, to solve this i used [checkout_cart_product_add_after] event, and then saved the data in [info_buyRequest] object